# Installation 11.10

Tags: 11.10

I have installed 11.10 on my laptop.HDDwas 160gb partioned 100gb as ext3 amd 20gb for swap.Have xp sp3 home on same drive.Installation went ok but now I do not have option to boot to dif

Comment: Can you click edit and complete your question?

Comment: You do not need 20GB for swap. 2GB should be enough depending on the amount of memory (RAM). What install options did you chose? Use Entire Disk? Install Alongside? Do Something Else?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you're not able to boot your Windows OS and it only boots into Ubuntu.
I suppose that Grub2 wasn't installed within your Ubuntu 11.10 installation
To install and load the grub items, just write these in your terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install grub2
sudo update-grub
```

the second line should output bootable partitions found (and you windows xp partition should also be there)

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Commands

```
grub>find /boot/grub/core.img ( this command will gives values of x and y)
grub>root (hdx,y) (use x and y values in previous command)
grub>kernel /boot/grub/core.img
grub>boot
```

After the boot command you will go into grub 2 menu. Select to boot up ubuntu, and run this command to restore grub.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Comment: improve formatting please, and promoting your blog isn't that helpfull in an answer, that belongs on your profile.